# Can't install/uninstall SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database, installation, sql, uninstall

When I try to install SQL Server Express I got this error

> Unable to install SQL Server (setup.exe)

Then I'm trying to uninstall everything related to the SQL server to avoid previous installation files, but I can't delete 1 folder (see image below)

[image: inlined]

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8GwiP.png

Comment: disable vss and retry

Comment: @djdomi yes i do it and thank you, but again i can't install because of `Unable to install SQL Server (setup.exe)` can you have any idea

Comment: unable to install is not a helpful error message. Please do always updates your question instead of keeping posting comments. Keep also note any progress in the original question